# Making comparison between specific columns two dataframes more efficient

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have two datasets, each with a number of email addresses and a record ID.
I am comparing the data, finding every record where an email in dataset1 matches a an email for a record in dataset 2.

I take the record id's from each dataset, name of the columns that match & values and add them to a dataset that I output at the end.

Ive done it the beginner way, with loops and although it works, its horribly inefficient.
For the two datasets, both with 150k records, its going to take a few thousand hours!

I appreciate any advise on how to improve this.

Note - I changed variable names in the below code so they would not indicate the systems im working with, apologies if i have introduced issues because of this.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the first CSV file (contact1_Contacts)
contacts_1_df = pd.read_csv("C:/temp/Contacts1.csv")

# Load the second CSV file (contact2_Contacts)
contacts_2_df = pd.read_csv("C:/temp/contacts2.CSV")


contacts_1_df.dropna(subset=['ContactId'], inplace=True)
contacts_2_df.dropna(subset=['ContactID'], inplace=True)

contacts_1_df.drop(['Full Name', 'Source Ref', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Birthdate', 'Mobile Phone', 'Date of Birth'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
contacts_2_df.drop(['Title', 'First Name','Middle Name', 'Surname', 'Maiden Name', 'Known As', 'Gender', 'DOB', 'Deceased?', 'Deceased Date', 'Phone Number', 'Nationality'], axis='columns', inplace=True)

#convert dataframes to lower
contacts_1_df = contacts_1_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
contacts_2_df = contacts_2_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

matches_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Contact1ContactGUID','Contact1ContactEmailType','Contact1ContactEmailValue','Contact2ContactID','Contact2EmailType','Contact2EmailValue'])

contact1_record_count = 0
contact2_record_count = 0


#for each contact1 contact
for contacts_1_index, contact1_row in contacts_1_df[['Preferred Email', 'Company Email', 'Email Address 2', 'Email 3', 'ContactId']].iterrows():
    #variable for columnindex so i can get the column name
    contact1_colindex = 0

    for contact1_email_col_value in contact1_row:

        #increment the column index
        contact1_colindex = contact1_colindex + 1
      
        #dont test for nan values
        if(contact1_email_col_value != 'nan'):

        
            for contact2_index, contact2_row in contacts_2_df[['Email'  ,'Email_1'  ,'Email_2'  ,'Email_3'  ,'Email_4','ContactID']].iterrows():

                #variable to hold the col index so i can get the column name
                contact2_colindex = 0

                for contact2_email in contact2_row:
 
                    #dont test for nan values
                    if(contact2_email != 'nan'):

                        if(contact2_email == contact1_email_col_value):
                            #print('****************MATCH****************')
                            match_row = {'Contact1ContactGUID': contact1_row[4], 'Contact1ContactEmailType': contact1_row.index[contact1_colindex], 'Contact1ContactEmailValue': contact1_email_col_value, 'Contact2ContactID': contact2_row[5], 'Contact2EmailType': contact2_row.index[contact2_colindex], 'Contact2EmailValue': contact2_email }
                            matches_df = pd.concat([matches_df, pd.DataFrame([match_row])], ignore_index=True)

                        contact2_colindex = contact2_colindex + 1


matches_df.to_csv('C:/temp/output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Can anyone advise how this can be made more efficient?

Comment: It will become easy for us to help if you have added sample data and expected output

Comment: (1) Panda's `merge` method can help. (2) The `concat` method is inefficient. Better collect new rows in a Python list and append all of them to the dataframe finally or in-between if the list contains many rows already.

Comment: @Martin using concat + merge as I propose is efficient. I experimented my solution with dataframes of 150K rows: results are obtained in less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restructure both dataframes in a way that make column names appear in rows.
One way to achieve that is to use `pd.concat()`

```
df1 = pd.concat([
    contacts_1_df[['ContactId', 'Preferred Email']].rename(columns={'Preferred Email': 'M1'}),
    contacts_1_df[['ContactId', 'Company Email']].rename(columns={'Company Email': 'M1'}),
    contacts_1_df[['ContactId', 'Email Address 2']].rename(columns={'Email Address 2': 'M1'}),
    contacts_1_df[['ContactId', 'Email 3']].rename(columns={'Email 3': 'M1'})])

df2 = pd.concat([contacts_2_df... (same approach, renaming as 'M2')
```

And then:̀

```
df1.merge(d2, left_on='M1, right_on='M2')
```

will give you pairs that match on any original mail column